# R, adding data frames in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, addition

In R, how to combine data frames in for loop.

I have data frames item1, item2, item3... and I want to combine them into pairs of item11, item12, item13, item21, item 22, ..., so below is the for loop:

I am having trouble finding the right code to access item1, item2, item3... individually.  In Python, it can be done using "item{}.format(i), item{}.format(j)", but is there a similar expression in R?  Or it needs to be done otherwisely?  Thanks in advance!!

```
for (j in 1:3){ 
  for (i in 1:3){ 
    assign(paste0("item", i, j), rbind(item_i, item_j))
  }
}
```

Comment: ```lapply(l, function(x) lapply(l, function(y) plyr::rbind.fill(x,y)))```

Comment: Thank you M-M!  I will try this code tomorrow; it probably will simplify some of my codes.

Comment: you can simply use rbind from base too, rbind.fill is just me playing on the safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your loops this should work:

```
for (j in 1:3){ 
  for (i in 1:3){ 
    assign(paste0("item", i, j), rbind(get(paste0("item_", i)), get(paste0("item_", j))))
  }
}
```

Comment: you are getting every combination doubled like this, not sure if that's intended. Author should clarify this @quesquestion

Comment: Thank you so much eastclintw00d!  It works exactly how I want it to!